# NSArray with Values, becomes empty when added to parent NSMutable Array

Tags: objective-c, arrays, xcode, xcode6

so here is my code.

```
NSMutableArray *arrProductSet = [NSMutableArray array];
int countProducts = (int)dicTemp.count;
int countStart = 0;
while(countStart < countProducts) {
    NSMutableArray *arrProductInfo = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSArray *arrProductSpecs = [NSArray array];

    NSString *strObjectKey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",countStart];
    arrProductInfo = [dicTemp objectForKey:strObjectKey];

    arrProductSpecs = [self getProductSpecs:[arrProductInfo objectAtIndex:0]];

    NSLog(@"Specs %@",arrProductSpecs); //<= arrProductSpecs has value
    [arrProductInfo addObject:arrProductSpecs];

    NSLog(@"Product %@",arrProductInfo); //<= arrProductSpecs becomes empty
    [arrProductSet addObject:arrProductInfo];
    countStart++;
}
```

im having trouble finding out why `arrProductSpecs` becomes empty whenever i add it to the product info array (`arrProductInfo`).

Also, if i log `arrProductSet` , the last `arrProductInfo` array's `arrProductSpecs` is not empty, it suprisingly have content

Here is my result:

```
(
    (
        168,
        ACR33U,
        "ACR33U-A1 SmartDuo Smart Card Reader",
        0,
        (
            /* empty, but this have value, if logged */
        )
    ),
    (
        155,
        ACR3801,
        "ACR3801 Smart Card Reader",
        (
            (
                "Host Interface",
                "USB Full Speed"
            ),
            (
                "Contact Smart Card Interface",
                "1 Full-sized smart card<br>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;ISO 7816 T=0 and T=1<br>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;Memory Cards"
            ),
            (
                "Built-in Peripherals",
                "1 LED"
            ),
            (
                "OS Supported",
                "Windows&nbsp;<br>Mac<br>Linux<br>Android"
            ),
            (
                "Compliance / Certifications",
                "PC/SC, CCID, Microsoft &reg; WHQL, USB Full Speed<br>FIPS 201, TAA<br>CE, FCC, IEC/EN 60950, VCCI, RoHS 2, REACH"
            ),
            (
                Applications,
                "e-Government<br>Banking & Payment<br>Access Control<br>Network Security<br>Public Key Infrastructure<br>e-Purse & Loyalty<br>"
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: That code looks very complicated.  You are allocating arrays and then assigning them from the temp dictionary.  Then getting product specs from product info and then adding product specs back into the product info?  You have devised a clever puzzle but I'm going to play it.  Simplify.

Comment: The whole code is weird. You create a new array on each iteration. After creating an array you assign a return value to the reference. You use `while` instead of `for` for an indexed iteration where a fast enumeration would be correct. …

Comment: You make the assumption that the dictionary keys are strings "0" to "99" for example if you have 100 keys. Is that correct? Then why on earth are you using a dictionary? Doesn't make sense.

Comment: `dicTemp` contains the products, without their specs, i cant iterate directly `dicTemp` cause i need to preseve the product order, `dicTemp` keys are the product arrangement

Comment: i need to transfer the product info from `dicTemp` to `arrProductSet`  and add the product specs while doing so